# Why the weighted fractional Sobolev semi-norm si not defined for $p=1$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

We defined the Weighted Sobolev semi-norm by $$[u]_{W^{s,p,\alpha }(\Omega )}^p=\iint_{\Omega \times \Omega }\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p |x|^{\alpha _1p}|y|^{\alpha _2p}}{|x-y|^{sp+d}}dxdy,$$
where $\alpha =\alpha _1+\alpha _2$, where $p\in(1,\infty )$. The thing I don't understand is why the case $p=1$ is not allowed ?

You can see reference [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04918.pdf) or [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022123617302732/1-s2.0-S0022123617302732-main.pdf?_tid=6c9c31d2-0b21-11e8-83cf-00000aacb361&acdnat=1517910062_ab8df5b2e08a939003987cbdb4827883). I really don't understand why $p=1$ can't be considered.

Comment: I certainly have answer for this these are fractional Sobolev spaces right?

Comment: Just a personal question are you work in a project right now? because you have some very tedious questions that need time to answer

Comment: @GuyFsone: Kind of. I also have this question in reference of the paper you put on the bounty I gave you here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640062/gagliardo-niremberg-inequality-on-annuli-proof  It's based on [3] Gagliardo : ulteriori proprietà di alcune classi di funzioni in più variabili, I'm sure the answer is in this paper, but I can't find it. Do you know where I can find this paper ?

Comment: I will try to see whether I can prove it

Comment: what are the restriction on $\alpha?$ I know already that $0<s<1$

Comment: @GuyFsone: as we can imagine : that $[u]_{W^{s,p,\alpha }}<\infty $

Comment: My question is ? $\alpha $ is in which range? can we take it arbitrally real? I doubt.

Comment: @GuyFsone: I follow this paper : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123617302732 and there is no specific restriction.